Looking for a black/white classic movie where some prisoners tried to escape?
Looks alike a 50s movie. Definitely was black/white Hollywood movie. 
Plot: Four prison inmates have been hatching a plan to literally dig out of jail when another prisoner is moved into their cell. They take a risk and share their plan with the newcomer to escape. The prisoners and friends break through the concrete floor using a bed post and begin to make their way through the sewer system
Unfortunately at that night one of them reported them so they failed to escape. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

@Paulie_D Was a Hollywood product. I can't remember anything else.

It sounds like Le Trou from 1961.

Just as four cell-mates are about to launch their elaborate escape
  from a tiny cell, a detainee from a cell-block under repair is
  transferred in. The four all face certain conviction and long
  sentences. Does the young new jail-mate have the same incentive and if
  so, can they trust him?


Thanks so much! How you found it? I searched more than 1000 times for classic prison escape movies but it wasn't exist in any list. Appreciated
